# What is the SAS format and informat for "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"?

Tags: datetime, format, sas, informat

## The Question

Please is there a built-in SAS format and informat for datetime in `mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss`?  For example:

`06/25/2015 03:02:01`  (June 25th 2015, 3 o'clock 2 minute 1 second).

## The Background

I am trying to parse a CSV flatfile to a SAS dataset in which a datetime column is currently presented in `mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss` format. I usually would just read it as a string, and then use the `substr()` function to pick out the date and time parts (as strings), use informat to resolve the SAS date and time (as numbers), and then combine them together to form a SAS datetime (as numbers). I am guessing there could be a cleaner way to do this and therefore am curious if there is already a built-in SAS datetime for `mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss` which will enable me to read this in one-parse, like this:

```
data test;
    infile "c:\temp\test.csv" dlm=',' missover;
    input 
        dtvar : <the datetime format for mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss>.
        var1 $
        var2 $
        ;
    format dtvar DATETIME19.;
run;
```

I have been doing lots of Google searches on this and no luck. Would be very grateful for this!

## EDIT / Update (on additional research efforts and findings)

Following the generous forum responses I have performed a comparison between the bespoke (home-made) format `mdyhms` and the SAS built-in format `mdyampm`.

The success factors are:

- Format case: be able to display 1748351045 as "06/25/2015 03:02:01"
- Informat case: be able to convert "06/25/2015 03:02:01" to 1748351045

The bespoke format `mdyhms` looks like this:

```
proc format;
  picture mdyhms
  other = '%0m/%0d/%Y %0H:%0M:%0S' (datatype=datetime);
run;
```

The comparison exercise below reveals some interesting observations:

- Format case: the bespoke format `mdyhms` is the winner.
- Informat case: the built-in format `mdyampm` is the winner.

Now the comparison exercise...

### Format Case

```
*** bespoke mdyhms as a format (Winner);
data try_format_mdyhms;
  x = "25JUN2015:03:02:01"dt;  /* 1750820521 */
  put x;                       /* 1750820521 */
  put x:mdyhms.;               /* 06/25/2015 03:02:01 */
run;

*** built-in mdyampm as a format (Loser);
data try_format_mdyampm;
  x = "25JUN2015:03:02:01"dt;  
  put x;                       /* 1750820521 */
  put x:mdyampm.;              /* 6/25/2015  3:02 AM */
run;
```

### Informat Case

```
*** bespoke mdyhms as an informat (Loser);
data try_informat_mdyhms;
  x = input("06/25/2015 03:02:01",mdyhms.);  /* informat fail (error) */
  put x; 
run;

*** built-in mdyampm as an informat (Winner);
data try_informat_mdyampm;
  x = input("06/25/2015 03:02:01",mdyampm.);  /* 1750820521 */
  put x;                                      /* 1750820521 */
run;
```

## Next step:

Are there any built-in (and/or bespoke) formats that will enable BOTH format and informat as per following success factors:

- Format case: be able to display 1748351045 as "06/25/2015 03:02:01"
- Informat case: be able to convert "06/25/2015 03:02:01" to 1748351045

(the bespoke `mdyhms` and built-in `mdyampm` seem to be able to achieve one of the two, but not both). Or have I missed anything?

Comment: possible duplicate of [sas informat datetime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1389544/sas-informat-datetime)

Comment: There are no build-in formats that can present a datetime value as you want it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two informats that can read the text "06/25/2015 03:02:01" and convert it to correct SAS datetime value:
ANYDTDTM and MDYAMPM

Comment: This looks good - `MDYAMPM` informat is probably safer though as I think with ANYDTDTM you may risk getting dates misread such as with `05/01/2015` being read as `01MAY` or `05JAN`

Answer (score -2):

Have a look at the stackoverflow answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1389544/sas-informat-datetime) for using datetime values. You should be able to update it with:

```
proc format ;
  picture mdyhms 
  other='%0m/%0d/%0Y %0H:%0M:%0S' (datatype=datetime)
;run ;
```

Comment: Actually - you need to tweak it ever so slightly to include the second that you have: `other='%0m/%0d/%0Y %0H:%0M:%0S'`

Comment: Unfortunately, picture formats don't work as informats, so I suspect this isn't terribly useful in this case.

Comment: There's another step in the linked question though to generate an informat using the format for the input of `cntlin` .... although @stigeide pointed out `MDYAMPM` informat which is much better...!