# Importing JSON dates into SAS gives incorrect $ format where datetime data expected

Tags: json, sas

I am trying to import data containing some date-columns/fields into SAS. The data are in JSON format, and hence need to be converted before import. This I use SAS libname JSON for.

But when I convert/import the data, SAS does not interpret the dates as proper dates, and allow me to manipulate data with date-constraints and so on. Instead, SAS imports the dates as Format = $ whatever that is. But the data show in the imported data. SAS imports the data without errors but any other date-field than the 'date_fi' in the data are not properly formatted as a date.

I am using the following script

> filename resp "C:\Temp\transaktioner_2017-07.json" lrecl=1000000000 ;
>   filename jmap "C:\Temp\transaktioner.map"; filename head
>   "c:\temp\header.txt";
>
> options metaserver="DOMAIN" metaport=8561 
>   metarepository="Foundation" metauser="USER"
>   metapass='CENSORED';
>
> libname CLIENT sasiola tag=SOMETAG port=10011
>   host="DOMAIN"
>   signer="https://CENSORED";
>
> proc http HEADEROUT=head
>   url='http://VALID_PATH/acubiz_sas/_design/view/_view/bymonth?key="2017-07"'
>
> method= "GET" CT="application/json" out=resp; run;   libname space
>   JSON fileref=resp map=jmap ;*automap=create;
>
> LIBNAME SASDATA BASE "D:\SASData";* outencoding='UTF-8';
>
> Data SASDATA.Transaktioner ; Set space.Rows_value; run;
>
> data *null*;   if exist("Acubiz.EMS_TRANSAKTIONER", "DATA") then
>   rc=dosubl("proc sql noprint; drop table Acubiz.EMS_TRANSAKTIONER;
>   quit;"); run;
>
> data Acubiz.EMS_TRANSAKTIONER; set sasdata.transaktioner; run;
>
> proc metalib;   omr (library="/Shared Data/SAS Visual
>   Analytics/Autoload/AcubizEMSAutoload/Acubiz_EMS"
>   repname="Foundation");   folder="/Shared Data/SAS Visual
>   Analytics/Autoload/AcubizEMSAutoload";   select ("EMS_TRANSAKTIONER");
>   run; quit;
>
> libname CLIENT clear;
>
> libname space clear;

For this conversion, I use the following JSON map.file called 'transaktioner.map'.

The field `date_fi` imports in the proper date format which I can manipulate as date-format in SAS Visual Analytics, but `confirmeddate_fi` does not.

The most important parts of this file are here.

```
{
  "NAME": "date_fi",
  "TYPE": "NUMERIC",
  "INFORMAT": [ "e8601dt19", 19, 0 ],
  "FORMAT": ["DATETIME", 20],
  "PATH": "/root/rows/value/date_fi",
  "CURRENT_LENGTH": 20
},


{
  "NAME": "confirmeddate_fi",
  "TYPE": "NUMERIC",
  "INFORMAT": [ "e8601dt19", 19, 0 ],
  "FORMAT": ["DATETIME", 20],
  "PATH": "/root/rows/value/confirmeddate_fi",
  "CURRENT_LENGTH": 20
},
```

Does any of you know how I might import the data and interpret the date-fields as such.

I have been messing with different informants in the JSON map-file to solve this riddle and have managed to get to where I can import the data without errors, but SAS does not interpret the date fields as such.

The actual fields are explained here with some examples (taken from the imported data):

```
Reference that works
date_fi:                    "2017-07-14T00:00:00"  (Apparantly never timestamped but use T00:00:00 - checked 9 instances)

Should work
invoicedate_fi:             "2017-08-01T00:00:00"  (Apparantly never timestamped but use T00:00:00 - checked 9 instances)
invoicedate_fi:             "2017-07-19T00:00:00"
invoicedate_fi:             "2017-07-17T00:00:00"

arrivaldate_fi:             "2017-08-13T00:00:00"  (Apparantly never timestamped but use T00:00:00 - checked 9 instances)

departuredate_fi:           "2017-08-09T00:00:00"  (Apparantly never timestamped but use T00:00:00 - checked 9 instances)



Do not work as numeric - even though they are specified as dates in map-file (for use with SAS JSON Libname)
markedreadydate_fi:         "2017-08-02T11:41:56"   (This field is often but not always timestamped)
markedreadydate_fi:         "2017-07-31T15:08:03"
markedreadydate_fi:         "2017-07-19T00:00:00"

confirmeddate_fi:           "2017-07-21T00:00:00"   (This field is often but not always timestamped)
confirmeddate_fi:           "2017-08-06T20:11:26"
confirmeddate_fi:           "2017-07-14T18:38:41"

confirmeddatefinance_fi:    "2017-07-31T15:54:10"   (This field is often but not always timestamped)
confirmeddatefinance_fi:    "2017-08-17T10:33:32"
confirmeddatefinance_fi:    "2017-07-26T08:21:34"

markedreadydate_fi:         "2017-07-19T00:00:00"   (This field is often but not always timestamped)
```

Does anyone have pertinent info on this issue, as I am at my wit's end? And have exhausted SAS Tech Support about this date-issue.

PS: As a proof of concept, we are importing approx 110.000 rows. And the import finishes without any errors.

A good PDF explaining the different ISO formats in SAS can be found [here](https://www.pharmasug.org/proceedings/2012/DS/PharmaSUG-2012-DS22-SAS.pdf)

Comment: Have you tried telling it the length is 10 and ignoring the time?

Comment: Which if you need the time is not helpful I know

Comment: E8601da10 based on the doc as the best informat

Comment: No I have not tried to crop off the time, as we might need time for our project.

I will definitely try the E8601da10 format tomorrow. Thanks.

Comment: What version of SAS do you have? If you have the latest version you can try using the JSON libname instead.

Comment: E8601da10 would be without time, so not what you need.

Comment: Possible answers at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1389544/sas-informat-datetime

Comment: I have latest SAS version and am using JSON libname as written in my question.

I will have a look at that linked question. Thanks

Comment: Apparantly the above link deals with creating your own informat. This is not my issue, as my informat exists already and is called 'e8601dt19'. This informat should take and correctly interpret my input data, as it exactly resemble the format used and shown in the lower part of my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparantly the solution is to start to import the date-columns as CHARACTERs instead of numbers. And hence do the conversion to date-format in the SAS code like so:

```
Data SASDATA.Transaktioner(drop=
arrivaldate_fi_temp
departuredate_fi_temp
confirmeddate_fi_temp
confirmeddatefinance_fi_temp
datetoshow_fi_temp 
date_fi_temp 
invoicedate_fi_temp 
markedreadydate_fi_temp
);
Set space.Rows_value(rename=(
confirmeddate_fi=confirmeddate_fi_temp 
datetoshow_fi=datetoshow_fi_temp 
date_fi=date_fi_temp 
invoicedate_fi=invoicedate_fi_temp 
markedreadydate_fi=markedreadydate_fi_temp 
arrivaldate_fi=arrivaldate_fi_temp 
departuredate_fi=departuredate_fi_temp 
confirmeddatefinance_fi=confirmeddatefinance_fi_temp
));
*length invoicedate_fi 8.;
format 
confirmeddate_fi 
datetoshow_fi 
date_fi 
invoicedate_fi 
markedreadydate_fi
arrivaldate_fi
departuredate_fi
confirmeddatefinance_fi
datetime20.;
if confirmeddate_fi_temp ne '' then confirmeddate_fi=input(confirmeddate_fi_temp,E8601DT19.); else confirmeddate_fi=.;
if datetoshow_fi_temp ne '' then datetoshow_fi=input(datetoshow_fi_temp,E8601DT19.); else datetoshow_fi=.;
if date_fi_temp ne '' then date_fi=input(date_fi_temp,E8601DT19.); else date_fi=.;
if invoicedate_fi_temp ne '' then invoicedate_fi=input(invoicedate_fi_temp,E8601DT19.); else invoicedate_fi=.;
if markedreadydate_fi_temp ne '' then markedreadydate_fi=input(markedreadydate_fi_temp,E8601DT19.); else markedreadydate_fi=.;
if arrivaldate_fi_temp ne '' then arrivaldate_fi=input(arrivaldate_fi_temp,E8601DT19.); else arrivaldate_fi=.;
if departuredate_fi_temp ne '' then departuredate_fi=input(departuredate_fi_temp,E8601DT19.); else departuredate_fi=.;
if confirmeddatefinance_fi_temp ne '' then confirmeddatefinance_fi=input(confirmeddatefinance_fi_temp,E8601DT19.); else confirmeddatefinance_fi=.;
run;
```

I will then remove all specifics for NUMERIC type for importing date-fields in the map file. This way the JSON libname does NOT take care of interpreting the date-formats. SAS does.

ie. the map file specification must be changed back to something like this for alle date-fields.

```
{
  "NAME": "date_fi",
  "TYPE": "CHARACTER",
  "PATH": "/root/rows/value/date_fi",
  "CURRENT_LENGTH": 19
},
```